# Facebook share button disappeared

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I am trying to implement my Facebook share button in my modal window with AngularJS. The share button shows the first time when I refresh the page, but the button is gone after I change my route to somewhere else and back to the modal window route page. How keep the Facebook button?
 Here is my code:

```html
<!--under my modal window <div>-->
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href='http://goose-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/gameInfo/{{gameId}}'></div>



<!--outside the modal window -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'API KEY',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe every time you switch routes, try running `FB.init` with your params?

Comment: You need to call `FB.XFBML.parse()` as explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse